# I've not changed my dashboard config, however showed me "User Configuration Error - The data source was improperly configured - Erorr ID: b776f69d"

Tags: dashboard, looker-studio

I was working with a dashboard on Looker Studio last week with no chane at all (the "code" remained the same) and this monday I opened Looker Studio and a whole segment has a problem now "User Configuration Error - The data source was improperly configured" with different errors IDs. ¿Any idea what should've been and how to fix it?

I checked every configuration and compaired with some other that actually works. And even they are the same, the problem still there. To sum, i haven't done anything but just compairing "codes".

Thanks in advance :)